# Create Union of Multiple Tables in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a union of multiple tables in Powershell to output in a user-friendly format as a report, similar to a `UNION` query in SQL.

I have the following code:

```
$ft = @{auto=$true; Property=@("MachineName", "Status", "Name", "DisplayName")}
$hosts = @("svr001", "svr002")
$report = @()
ForEach ($h in $hosts) {
    $results = Get-Service -CN $h -Name MyService
    $report += $results | Format-Table @ft
    # Other things occur here, which is why I'm creating $report for output later.
}
Write-Output $report
```

The output of this code is as follows:

```
MachineName  Status Name       DisplayName
-----------  ------ ----       -----------
svr001      Running MyService  MyServiceDisplayName



MachineName  Status Name       DisplayName
-----------  ------ ----       -----------
svr002      Running MyService  MyServiceDisplayName
```

Since you simply add arrays to do a union in Powershell (i.e.,
`$union = @(0, 1, 2) + @(3, 4, 5)`), my initial thought was that I should
get the following output:

```
MachineName  Status Name       DisplayName
-----------  ------ ----       -----------
svr001      Running MyService  MyServiceDisplayName
svr002      Running MyService  MyServiceDisplayName
```

In retrospect, I think I understand why I do **not** get this output, but I'm
unclear how to create a union of the two tables from the first output example into a single table as in the second, and I haven't been able to locate anything in the docs or examples online that would send me in the right direction.

Comment: Move `| Format-Table .......` to the last line after `write-output $report`. Never save output from `format-*` cmdlets.

Comment: For the record, You can pass multiple computer names to Get-Service... The ForEach loop isn't needed for that part of your code.

Comment: While I can see the point about not saving the output from `Format-*` cmdlets, doing that generates the following output: `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerSystem.ServiceProcess.ServiceController System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController`.

Comment: @TimFerrill--I had tried that, and it only output results back for the first server, so I didn't think that it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `Format-Table` to the last command. `Format-*` cmdlets create special format-objects that you can't work with manually so theres no point in saving them. When you save the result of `Format-*` to an array, you're saving the "report" which is why you get two tables in the output (array consists of two reports).

Collect the data first, then use `Format-Table` when you want to display the results.

```
$ft = @{auto=$true; Property=@("MachineName", "Status", "Name", "DisplayName")}
$hosts = @("svr001", "svr002")
$report = @()
ForEach ($h in $hosts) {
    $results = Get-Service -ComputerName $h -Name MyService
    $report += $results
    # Other things occur here, which is why I'm creating $report for output later.
}

#Write-Output is not necessary as it is default behaviour
$report | Format-Table @ft
```

Sample output (used `wuauserv` as servicename):

```
MachineName  Status Name     DisplayName   
-----------  ------ ----     -----------   
localhost   Stopped wuauserv Windows Update
frode-pc    Stopped wuauserv Windows Update
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Get-Service` Cmdlet also supports an array of strings for the `-ComputerName` parameter. This works for me:

```
Get-Service -CN $hosts -Name MyService | Format-Table @ft
```

Sample Output using wuauserv:

```
MachineName  Status Name     DisplayName   
-----------  ------ ----     -----------   
Tim-SRV1    Running wuauserv Windows Update
Tim-SRV2    Stopped wuauserv Windows Update
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and belongs as a comment. His sample says that there are more commands in the "foreach host"-loop, so there's no guarantee you could remove the foreach-loop.

Comment: In my test of this, however, doing `Get-Service -CN $hosts -Name MyService | Format-Table @ft` only gets the service for the first server in the list.  I'm using Powershell 2.0, if that matters, and Powershell version is **not** something I have control over in this environment.

Comment: Yes, in PowerShell 2.0 you only receive the first (at least when testing with `powershell -version 2`) on a PS 5.0 computer. Don't have a Win7-comp with 2.0 documentation to verify if it's a bug or if array-support is missing. On PS 3+ it should work fine with array-input